# oracle goldengate works fine, but i keep getting OGG-00945

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

Looks like `goldengate` is working fine, but I keep receiving error at target in `mgr.prm` report file as

> WARNING OGG-00945  Startup of GGCMD ^E failed (Parameter file /u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0.2/ogg/dirprm/^E.prm does not exist for ^E)

I receive this warning every 1hr in `MGR.rpt`, but my replication is working good.

What can be the issue? Any pointers?

Thanks
harish

Answer (score 0):

You have a incorrect `AUTORESTART` parameter in `mgr.prm`.  Edit the Manager parameter file and remove any incomplete or unwanted `AUTORESTART` parameters, like these:

```
AUTORESTART ^E
AUTORESTART .
AUTORESTART
```